# Alert box in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I tried searching the internet for ways to display a javascript alert box in asp.net, but none of them worked.
My code:

```
string message;
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   if ((int) Application["taken"] == 1)
   {
       message = "Username and email already in use!";
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Username and email already in use!')", true);
   }
   else if ((int) Application["taken"] == 2)
   {
       message = "Username already in use!";
       ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Username already in use!')", true);
   }
   else if ((int) Application["taken"] == 3)
   {
       message = "Email already in use!";
       sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'> window.onload=function(){alert('" + message + "')} </script>");
       ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
   }
```

what do I need to do?

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: nope, the alert just doesn't show up, I know the if is working tho, because if I response.write instead it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `RegisterStartupScript` ?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Username already in use!')", true);
```

[image]

Comment: I have put the very simple code and screenshot.  Could you please try that code in the blank new page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call script twice, instead write code for alert twice in same script.
You can write your javascript method at your aspx page or can write in a javascript file and include it. Then register it at cs page as

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), “ShowStatus”, “javascript:ShowMessages(‘First Message’,’Second Message’);”, true);

function ShowMessages(msg1, msg2) {
 alert(msg1);
 alert(msg2);
}
```

For details please click on this [link](https://codewala.net/2011/11/24/page-clientscript-registerstartupscript-is-not-working/)

Comment: like this?

       <%
       if ((int) Application["taken"] == 1)
       {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "javascript:ShowAlert('Username and email already in use!');", true);
       }
and jscript:

    function ShowAlert(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

Comment: Yes! But you don't need to write <% before if(), that you have written in your comment.

Comment: Can you check with int.parse(Application["taken"]) == 1 inside your if condition.

Comment: wait so where do I write the if() if not in the aspx page? in the cs? under public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page?

Comment: In your question you have mention some if-else condition. For example instead of this if ((int) Application["taken"] == 1) write if(int.parse(Application["taken"]) == 1) and similarly in else if condition. You just need to update to int.parse. And then check once with my above code.

Comment: See you need to keep this function in js cript file. ShowMessages(msg1, msg2){}

Comment: yeah I know, I have the if else, but im not sure if I where I wrote it is correct, image: https://gyazo.com/05add63fc38ef799261f211f7364d3b4
when I try to change it to int.parse it give me this error: https://gyazo.com/9df14b0c28cc62ee1dfe907845f49198
also my jscript code just incase, image : https://gyazo.com/7f5df86174f7067021cbba54b238bf43

Comment: First image is correct. Did you debug and check whether your Application["taken"] value is 1,2 or 3 or not.